# with the new Graph API, is it possible to access info about all the group's user is a member of?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-group, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am trying to write code to access info about all the groups a user has joined. It's supposed to work with (me?fields=groups) in the graph api explorer.

It appears I can only access the groups I created.
Has there been any change in the API? 
or can someone point out a solution
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`/me/groups` (or `/me?fields=groups`) returns a list of groups you manage only, with the `user_managed_groups` permission. You cannot get a list of ALL groups the user is a member of anymore, this was changed a long time ago.

Comment: nice of you.. What could have been the reason behind facebook api preventing to get the list of all the groups that I am member of. And do you know of any alternatives to get all the groups.

Comment: there are no alternatives. i assume it is because you do not want any regular group member to be able to get all group data to some external website, unless it is the group admin. data about the group is only relevant to the group admin.